# how to see webpack warnings

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am bit new to the Webpack.

My project is the combination typescript  and webpack. 
when I rebuild the solution in visual studio, seeing one warning in the webpack popup.
[image]

I don't see any issue with my typescript code modifications. 
I would like to see the complete warning message showing in the webpack. 
Could someone tell me the way to check this?

Comment: we get the complete message in output window. I just have checked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we get the complete message in output window. I just have checked it.